# How do I re-checkout a submodule in Git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm using Git 2.17.2 on Mac.  Somehow the submodule I was using in my project got screwed up and I would like to re-import (connect?) the submodule from scratch.  Within my project, I removed the directory

```
davea$ git rm DBConnector
```

and then ran

```
davea$ git submodule add https://myuser@dev.azure.com/MainCo/SubCo/_git/DBConnector
A git directory for 'DBConnector' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin    https://dev.azure.com/MainCo/SubCo/_git/DBConnector
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  https://myuser@dev.azure.com/MainCo/SubCo/_git/DBConnector
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.
```

thinking I messed up something earlier, I tried

```
davea$ git submodule rm DBConnector
usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] (--all| [--] <path>...)
   or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--checkout|--merge|--rebase] [--[no-]recommend-shallow] [--reference <repository>] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] absorbgitdirs [--] [<path>...]
```

so I'm a little confused.  What do I need to do to re-add this submodule from scratch and clear out any references to it that may be preventing my re-adding it?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of doing a `git rm` on a submodule, it is [advised](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#_submodules) to do a `git submodule deinit` (might as well use the `--force` option in case you have any unmodified changes). After that, do a `git submodule add` and I think that should fix the problem.

Feel free to comment if there is any problem in this method!

Best

Comment: I ran "git submodule deinit --force --all", which produced no output (or errors), but then running "git add submodule myurl" resulted in the error, "A git directory for 'DBConnector' is found locally with remote(s): "

Comment: Adding `--force` to the `git submodule add` will override this and help you add the submodules.